# Create Custom Brush With Png(transparent) Image and a Background Color

Tags: wpf, silverlight, brush, brushes, imagebrush

I want to create a custom brush in WPF that will be applied to a rectangle.
Fill= myCustomBrush.
theCustomBrush contains a png image (ImageBrush) ,and contanins a color in background (SolidColorBrush).
I want to create a custombrush with this two standards brushes.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VisualBrush for this. Example

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBackgroundColor" Color="Green"/>
<VisualBrush x:Key="RectangleBrush">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource MyBackgroundColor}"/>
            <Image Source="BackgroundImageSource"/>
        </Grid>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>

<!-- ... -->

<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource RectangleBrush}"/>
```